# My iPhone charge percentage jumps dramatically

Tags: iphone

So sometimes my phone will be at 20%, and it'll die before going lower. Just now, it was at 4%, so I plugged it in, and it went up to 11%. After waiting 60 seconds, it's up to 34% now and has sat at 34% for the past minute or so.

What is wrong with my phone? It hasn't always been like this.

Comment: bmike's right, the battery is no good. You can get a replacement battery from iFixit for $40 https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-6-Replacement-Battery/IF268-002-2. The battery isn't very hard to get to (just taking the digitizer assembly off and removing a bracket holding the battery in place, the whole thing's just 8 screws), but actually removing it is somewhat tough, as there are adhesive tabs that need to be removed from under the battery and they always break off.

Answer (score 3):

Non smooth charging or consumption indicates a hardware failure - usually battery related. If it's in warranty - that usually ends up the first attempt to remedy the symptom.

Comment: I bought the iPhone 6 in the first week it came out. I don't think it would still be in warranty, would it?

Comment: Unfortunately not since the release date was more than 12 months ago (September 19 2014)

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I'm very familiar with this but I wouldn't rush the User to just change the battery when the problem could be related to the actual board as well

Answer (score -4):

just disable finger print scanner or delete finger prints if you have any.

Comment: There's no reason this could fix the OP's issue. If you think it could, please provided sources for your answer!